# ¿Cómo convertir o transformar un número décimal a horas usando javascript?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo hacer para convertir un valor decimal a horas usando JavaScript?

Estuve revisando `Excel` y tiene una forma muy fácil de hacerlo, pero esto quiero llevarlo a JS.

¿Existe alguna forma de realizar el siguiente cálculo?

[image: Imagen de referencia en Excel]

Esa es la manera que Excel convierte un valor a horas. Intente pasarlo a minutos pero no tuve éxito, Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Tu input será el equivalente a 5.61??

Answer (score 3):

La solución es bastante simple.

- La parte entera, representa la cantidad de unidades completas (*horas, minutos, segundos*)
- La parte decimal, representa el porcentaje de una unidad.

Por ejemplo, convertir `5.61 horas` es igual a:

- `5 horas`
- `61%` de una hora, expresado en minutos sería:

  ```
  61 * 60 minutos / 100 = 36.6 minutos
  ```

Entonces `36.6 minutos` es igual a:

- `36 minutos`
- `60%` de un minuto, expresado en segundos sería:

  ```
  60 * 60 segundos / 100 = 36 segundos
  ```

#### Solución:

```js
function decimalAHora(decimal) {
  let horas = Math.floor(decimal), // Obtenemos la parte entera
    restoHoras = Math.floor(decimal % 1 * 100), // Obtenemos la parde decimal
    decimalMinutos = restoHoras * 60 / 100, // Obtenemos los minutos expresado en decimal

    minutos = Math.floor(decimalMinutos), // Obtenemos la parte entera
    restoMins = Math.floor(decimalMinutos % 1 * 100), // Obtenemos la parde decimal
    segundos = Math.floor(restoMins * 60 / 100); // Obtenemos los segundos expresado en entero

  return `${('00'+horas).slice(-2)}:${('00'+minutos).slice(-2)}:${('00'+segundos).slice(-2)}`;
}

let number = 5.61;
console.log(number, '==', decimalAHora(number))
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, me estaba costando un poco hacer todo esto procedimiento