# Como convertir hora decimal en H:m:s

Tags: php

Necesito  convertir una hora del tipo 6.76 a 6:47 en PHP y no encuentro información de como serían los cálculos, ni si existe alguna función en PHP que calcule esto.

agradecería cualquier información..

Saludos...

Comment: y por qué serían 47 min???

Comment: Buen día, Carbon tiene muchas funciones, sin más información de lo que deseas hacer y lo que has intentado es imposible dar una respuesta más precisa que el ejemplo genérico que puse en la respuesta.

Comment: Hola Aldeano, si te interesa saber como es el cálculo para llegar al resultado te invito a leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/480480/16597)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convierte la hora a segundos y aplícale a una [función de tiempo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gmdate.php) de PHP

```php
php > $dec = 6.76;
php > echo gmdate('H:i:s', $dec * 3600);
06:45:36
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías utilizar `Carbon` para hacerlo.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
<?php

// Ajusta la ruta de acuerdo con la estructura de tu proyecto
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

function floatToDateTime($floatDuration)
{
    $duration = Carbon::now()->addHours($floatDuration);

    // Con locale cambias el idioma
    // 6 partes incluye años, meses, días, horas, minutos y segundos
    return $duration->locale('es')->diffForHumans(['parts' => 6]);
}

$floatDuration = 12345.6789;
$durationString = floatToDateTime($floatDuration);

echo $durationString;
```

Esto devuelve:

```
en 1 año 4 meses 3 semanas 6 días 8 horas 59 minutos
```

Revisa la documentación, en este ejemplo genérico se muestra la diferencia para humanos que provee la librería, pero tal vez quieras únicamente el formato numérico sin las palabras intermedias.